# WordPress Gutenberg get block styles from useBlockProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am adding styles when registering my block:

```
styles: [
   { name: "my-style-1", label: "Style Name" }
   { name: "my-style-2", label: "Style Name 2" }
],
```

In the edit() and save() function how can I see which style/classname was selected?

I tried for example:

```
edit( { attributes, setAttributes, styles } ) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();
    const { quote, name, title } = attributes;

    console.log(styles);
    console.log(blockProps.styles);

    ...
```

But it returns undefined.

I need to use the styles for conditions for example...

```
if (style == 'my-style-1') {
   // do something if style 1 was selected
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected Block Style name as defined in your *styles[{...}]* is available in the `edit()` function as `className`:

```
edit({ attributes, setAttributes, className}) {
    console.log(className);
    ...
}
```

I'd suggest if you want to reorder elements based on their style, create Block Styles and use CSS flexbox to manage the reordering, eg `display:flex` for your wrapper div and `order: ...` for the child elements (like `<img>` and `<p>`). By using styles, when the content is saved the underlying HTML markup doesn't change so less change of getting the dreaded 'block validation' error (plus you get a preview of the style in the Editor). Make sure to save `blockProps` in the `save()` so the selected class is applied, eg:

```
edit({ attributes, setAttributes, className }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();
    console.log(className);

    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <h2>Hello</h2><img />
        </div>
    );
},
save({ attributes }) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
    return (<div {...blockProps}><h2>Hello</h2><img /></div>)
}
```

The generated class applied to the `<div>` will be `.wp-block-myblock-name .is-style-my-style-1`

Comment: For me property 'className' was undefined when accessed as per `Edit( { className } )`. I can access the prop as `useBlockProps().className` or `Edit( { attributes: { className } } )`. The bonus of the latter is it contains only the selected style class. Note: that attribute was generated by the styles API - I have no attributes manually defined.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Block Variations](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/) instead of Block Styles. When creating a variation you can assign attribute values.

For example:

**index.php**

```
registerBlockType('xy/yourBlock', {
  title: 'xy',
  description: 'xy',
  attributes: {
    quote: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    title: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    style: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  },
  variations: [
    {
        name: 'my-style-1',
        isDefault: true,
        title: 'Style Name',
        attributes: { style: 'my-style-1' },
        scope: 'transform',
    },
    {
        name: 'my-style-2',
        title: 'Style Name 2',
        attributes: { style: 'my-style-2' },
        scope: 'transform',
    },
  ],
})
```

With scope: 'transform' you can select your variation in the block settings on the right side. Once a variation is selected you can access it in your edit and save file like any other attribute.

```
edit( { attributes, setAttributes } ) {
    const { quote, name, title, style } = attributes;

    console.log(style);

    if (style == 'my-style-1') {
      // do something if style 1 was selected
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am not sure if this is the right approach. Block variations seem to create multiple blocks that have different control panel settings. I am trying to create different simple styles for the same block. For example, a style where an image is below text, another style where the image is above the text. This seems to be best with styles because they can also be previewed.